# Javascript AWS-SDK to generate signed download url for a specific IP address

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

Currently I am using the Javascript AWS-SDK to generate signed download url's for objects in a S3 Bucket, How ever I would also like to restrict the signed url by ip address. Is this possible? I.E If a user gets a signedUrl for a specific file they should only be able to use that link if they are on a specific IP. I am not using cloudfront.

Comment: CloudFront supports this natively, but S3 does not.  I *think* it's possible to do this with S3 if you bring Security Token Service into the mix, obtaining a set of temporary credentials and then using those to sign the request, instead of using your key directly.  A security token can have embedded IAM policy constraints, which should include support for a source IP restriction.   Sounds complicated but it probably is not as bad as it sounds.  I'll test it.

Comment: Of course, the simple solution is to connect a CloudFront distribution to the bucket, and use CloudFront signed URLs to authorize these requests.

Comment: So the one tool I am not using, but mentioned, is the tool that would make it simple to implement. Sounds good. Thanks. I will look into it.